# Why is the result cache always disabled in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, caching, oracle11g

I'm trying to enable the result cache in Oracle 11g. I have used Enterprise Manager to change the `result_cache_max_size` and `result_cache_max_result` values to '1M' and '100' respectively (maybe these aren't optimal settings, but I'm just trying to get it to work!).

After I make these changes I use the following query to see if the changes have really been made:

```
select * from V$PARAMETER where LOWER("NAME") like '%result_cache%';
```

I can see that both have been set correctly. However, when I run queries with the result_cache hint, I can see from the Autotrace that the cache isn't being used. If I then run the following query:

```
SELECT dbms_result_cache.status() FROM dual;
```

I can see that it's status is 'DISABLED'. Restarting the database just makes the `result_cache_max_size` parameter go back to 0 (disabled).

How can I enable the result cache?

Comment: Check if `shared_pool_size` is set. Result cache consumes shared pool's memory.

Comment: shared_pool_size is 0 - what should I set that to?

Comment: Set it to a value that is calculated according to your needs. Plus. Result cache is an Enterprise Edition feature. It looks like you are using at least standard edition, because in enterprise edition if you set `result_cache_max_size` and do not set `shared_pool_size`, `dbms_result_cache.status()` should return `bypass` not `disabled` like in your case. What edition of RDBMS you are using?

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov I'm using standard edition, so that probably explains why it doesn't work! I guess I'll need to upgrade...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the comments, it's because result cache is an Enterprise Edition feature only and I have Standard Edition.